# Google Sheets: Number Format option of horizontal axis labels in a histogram

Tags: google-sheets, histogram, number-formatting

I would like to change the number format of the horizontal axis labels of a histogram. Some tutorials mention that this should work, e.g.

- [New chart text and number formatting options in Sheets](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/07/customize-chart-text-numbers-google-sheets.html)
- [How To☝️ Change Axis Scales In A Google Sheets Chart](https://spreadsheetdaddy.com/google-sheets/axis-scale)

However, the option to change the number format seems to be gone, see the following screenshot:
[image: Sceenshot]

Is it possible that Google removed that feature? And/or can this be done differently?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is more suitable for Superuser, but:

In "Chart editor" select "Setup", find option "Treat labels as text" and untick it:

[image]

Now you can choose format for horizontal axis:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and potentially misplacing this question. However, the option "Treat labels as text" does not occur for histogram charts, and "Number format" unfortunately neither.

Comment: Then in Setup look for option "Use row X as labels"

Comment: Sorry, but that option isn't there, either. There is only "Use column X as labels". But the histogram cannot be drawn when it's checked, which makes sense as there couldn't be any binning then.